# Snake doesn't appear in the frame of a Java game

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make snake game in java but the snake doesn't shown up on the screen and I don't know why ... here is my code ... I've made it in three classes

```
 public class SnakeGame extends JFrame {

 public SnakeGame(){
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBackground(Color.green);
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setTitle("Snake Game");
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
     play p = new play();
     add(p);
     pack();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SnakeGame();
}
}



public class play extends JPanel implements Runnable{

public static final int WIDTH = 700,HEIGHT = 700;
private ArrayList<SnakeDesign> snake;

public play(){
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    snake = new ArrayList<SnakeDesign>();

}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    for(int i=0;i<snake.size();i++){
        snake.get(i).paintSnake(g);
       }
     }

@Override
public void run() {
    repaint();
}
```

}

```
 public class SnakeDesign {

private int Xcoor, Ycoor, width, height;

public SnakeDesign(int Xcoor, int Ycoor,int tileSize){
    this.Xcoor = Xcoor;
    this.Ycoor = Ycoor;
    width = tileSize;
    height = tileSize;

}
public void paintSnake (Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawRect(Xcoor*width, Xcoor*height, width, height);
}
```

so please can anyone say why the snake doesn't appear ... thanks in advance

Comment: You should not override `paint()` method but `paintComponent()` instead. See [A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html)

Comment: Out of topic, but try libGDX or a real game engine, Swing isn't designed to make games ;)

Answer (score 6):

1. don't override the JPanel's `paint(Graphics g)` method but rather override its `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method. There are many reasons for this, and some include

   - The paint method is responsible for drawing the component **and** drawing its borders and children, and so if its Graphics object is changed, you may cause unwanted and hard to debug side effects on a component's borders and child components.
   - A JPanel or JComponent's paintComponent method uses double buffering by default, and so if you use this for animation (and you are) using this will give you a noticeable much smoother animation.
2. Call the super's `super.paintComponent(g)` method in your `paintComponent(Graphics g)` override.
3. You've created a Runnable, but I don't see you putting it in a Thread or starting the Thread.
4. Always call `setVisible(true)` **last** after adding all components, not before.
5. Class names should start with an upper case letter.
6. Where do you add elements into your ArrayList, i.e., where do you have `snake.add(...)` where you pass a body element into the snake? If you give your snake no body, what will it show?
7. Use a Swing Timer to drive your animation. This will allow you to get rid of the need for a Runnable interface (which is currently only calling `run()` and so it is essentially doing nothing).

Comment: i added snake.get(i).paintSnake(g); but still nothing appears

Comment: @user3605253: But again, where do you have `snake.add(...)` anything? As written now, your snake's size will be 0, so your for loop where you paint it will not do anything.